# Как передать данные при обратном переходе из второго ViController'a в первый используя closure?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Имеется два ViewController'a: ViewController1 и ViewController2. На ViewController1 есть 2 Label'a. По тапу на каждый из этих Label'ов с помощью NavigationController осуществляется переход на ViewController2. Отслеживание тапов с помощью gestureRecognizer. Каким образом можно осуществить возврат на первый ViewController1 и передачу в него строки со второго ViewController2 с помощью именно closure?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден, и он довольно прост. Если кому-то интересно, то весь ответ в этой статье https://swiftbook.ru/post/tutorials/pass-data/